# space between menu and QtOpenGL.QGLWidget

Tags: python, qt, pyopengl

can anybody tell me what's wrong in the following simple source code. In the picture below you can see my problem. I want a widget which consists of a menu and a QGLWidget, but the QGLWidget overlaid the menu. If I use QtGui.QWidget instead it works fine. How can I increase the space between these elements?

diagram 1:

[image]

code of QGLWidget :

```
class Profile(QtOpenGL.QGLWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Profile, self).__init__(parent)

    def initializeGL(self):
        GL.glClearColor(1.0, 1.0 , 1.0, 1.0)

    def paintGL(self):
        GL.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_MODELVIEW)
        GL.glLoadIdentity()
        GL.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
```

code of test widget which works fine:

```
class TestWidget(QtGui.QWidget): 
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(TestWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        editor = QtGui.QTextEdit()
        grid   = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        grid.addWidget(editor, 1,1)

        self.setLayout(grid)
```

code of main widget:

```
class ProfileDetectWidget(QtGui.QWidget): 
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(ProfileDetectWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.ogl_widget = Profile()
        # self.ogl_widget = TestWidget() 

        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        grid.addWidget(self.ogl_widget, 2,1)

        self.createActions()
        self.createMenus()

        self.setLayout(grid) 
        self.resize(420,320)

    def createActions(self):
        self.openAct = QtGui.QAction('Open...', self)

    def createMenus(self):
        fileMenu = QtGui.QMenu("File", self)
        fileMenu.addAction(self.openAct)

        menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(self)
        menubar.addMenu(fileMenu)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(["PyQt OpenGL"])
    widget = ProfileDetectWidget()
    widget.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code of the main widget I changed

```
grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
grid.addWidget(self.ogl_widget, 2,1)
```

to

```
space = QtGui.QSpacerItem(0,15)
grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
grid.addItem(space)
grid.addWidget(self.ogl_widget, 2,1)
```

and it seems to work.